# Mocha Testing a Nested Model

Tags: express, mongoose, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

Trying to write a test for a nested model but can't get it working:

Model:

```
const EmployeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {type: String, required: true},
  lastName: { type: String, required: true}
});

const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  streetAddress: { type: String, required: true },
  country: { type: String, required: true },
  employees:[EmployeeSchema]    
}, { timestamps: true});
```

Controller:

```
function create(req, res, next) {
  const company = new Company({
    name: req.body.name,
    streetAddress: req.body.streetAddress,
    country: req.body.country    
  });

  company.employees.push(req.employees);

  company.save()
    .then(savedCompany => res.json(savedCompany))
    .catch(e => next(e));
}
```

Test:

```
    describe('## Company APIs', () => {
      let company = {
        name: "Test Company",
        streetAddress: "123 Fake Street",
        country: "A Country"    
      };
      company.employees.push({firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe"});

  describe('# POST /api/company', () => {
    it('should create a new company', (done) => {
      request(app)
        .post('/api/company')
        .send(company)
        .expect(httpStatus.OK)
        .then((res) => {
          expect(res.body.name).to.equal(company.name);
          expect(res.body.streetAddress).to.equal(company.streetAddress);
          expect(res.body.country).to.equal(company.country);
          company = res.body;
          done();
        })
        .catch(done);
    });
  });
```

The above gives: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

I've tried a few other things but this is the most promising result, for some reason I just can't seem to populate the embedded model as part of setting up the unit test.

Comment: It might not be the answer but I spotted that this line `company.employees.push({firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe"});` in the test. It tries to push an object `employees` which doesnt exist in company. And it doesnt assert `company.employees` then I think you can remove that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this, hopefully this helps someone in the future.

**Test:**

```
it('should associate an employee with the company', (done) => {    
      var employee = new Employee();
      company.employees.push(employee);      
      request(app)
        .put(`/api/company/${company._id}`)
        .send(company)
        .expect(httpStatus.OK)
        .then((res) => {
          expect(res.body.employees).to.be.an('array')
          expect(res.body.employees).to.contain(employee.id)
          done();
        })
        .catch(done);
    });
```

**Controller:**
Adding this to handle multiple additions:

```
if (req.body.employees != null) {      
    req.body.employees.forEach(function(employee) {      
      company.employees.push(employee);
    }, this);
  }
```